# Random ListView begavior asp.net

Tags: listview, random

I took a course at **asp.net** and now a year after I want to make a project.
I was thinking about an ecommerce website.

I`m displaying my products using`ListView` from the **DB (MSSQL)**.
I want to make it Random - so whenever I refresh the page I see the products in a different order.

How should I approach ?

Thanks guys :)

```
         <asp:ListView ID="lvProducts" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr><td><img src="<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><h1><%#Eval("Brand") %></h1></td></tr>
                <tr><td><h2><%#Eval("Model") %></td></tr>
                <tr><td><h3><%#Eval("Price") %></td></tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

code behind:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter ProductData = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TEST", conn);
    DataTable dtProduct = new DataTable();
    ProductData.Fill(dtProduct);

    lvProducts.DataSource = dtProduct;
    lvProducts.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code to get better answer

Comment: I did, can you pleasce check it out?